# array of strings to array of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

My model is giving me an array of strings as json, and I need an array of objects for my api to function correctly on the client side. In my model I define the json as

```
def as_json(options={})
    super(:only => [:price, :available, :location_id, :beer_id], :methods => [:name, :brewery, :style, :label_url, :description, :id])
  end
```

This is giving me a response

```
{"available":"on","beer_id":1,"created_at":"2013-05-31T16:45:09Z","description":"Good","id":1,"location_id":1,"price":"3.0","size":"16.0","updated_at":"2013-05-31T16:45:09Z"}
```

which is obviously missing the `[ ]` indicating it is an array of objects. Is there a simple way to convert this array of strings into an array of objects?

EDIT: My original response which was working fine was

```
[{"available":"on","beer_id":1,"created_at":"2013-05-31T16:45:09Z","description":"Good","id":1,"location_id":1,"price":"3.0","size":"16.0","updated_at":"2013-05-31T16:45:09Z"}]
```

My ios app is crashing because it doesn't think the current response is of type NSDictionary because it is NSString. After looking around it appears that some change I made to the rails app changed the json response. The only clue I have is the missing brackets when I look at what was working and what is now not working.

Comment: What do you mean by array of objects? JSON is essentially a way of storing data in a string, so if you're hoping to be able to store Time objects or the like, it isn't going to happen. Edit your question to include an example of desired behavior as well and it'll be easier to give you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, your response is not an array of strings, it's just a single JSON object.

If you need to convert the object into 1-element array of objects, just enclose it into [ and ]. :)

Comment: Thanks, stupid question then. How do I add the [and] to the response?

Comment: The above works if you have an object, not a string. For string, use `'[' + my_string + ']'` or `"[${my_string}]"`